# using c++ packaged_task to construct producer-consumer pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, packaged-task

I am trying to packaged_task to create a producer-consumer patten
code is as following : 
`test_thread9_producer1` and `test_thread9_producer2` push task into a queue
and `test_thread9_consumer1` retrieve task from the queue to execute

However when running `test_thread9`, it executes task correctly but finished with debug error : abort has been called. I'm not sure why ? Can anyone help me get more understanding of `packaged_task`?

A second issue: consumer is running with `while(1)` loop, I can not think of graceful way
to let `test_thread9_consumer1` exit when two producers finished pushing all tasks into queue and `test_thread9_consumer1`  finished executing all tasks in the queue.  Can anyone give me some suggestion ?

```
void test_thread9()
{
    std::thread t1(test_thread9_producer1);
    std::thread t2(test_thread9_producer2);
    std::thread t3(test_thread9_consumer1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
} 

std::deque<std::packaged_task<int()>>task_q;
std::mutex lock9;

int factial_calc2(int in)
{
    int ret = 1;
    for (int i = in; i > 1; i--)
    {
        ret = ret*i;
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
    std::cout << "input is " << in << "result is " << ret << std::endl;
    return ret;
}

void test_thread9_producer1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
        std::packaged_task<int()> t1(std::bind(factial_calc2, i));
        task_q.push_back(std::move(t1));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void test_thread9_producer2()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 2)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
        std::packaged_task<int()> t1(std::bind(factial_calc2, i));
        task_q.push_back(std::move(t1));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}


void test_thread9_consumer1()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;
    while (1)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
            if (!task_q.empty())
            {
                t = std::move(task_q.front());
                task_q.pop_front();
            }
        }
        t();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you ran it in the debugger, where did the program stop?

Answer (score 0):

**Why does it crash ?**

If your consumer thread finds an empty queue, it will nevertheless try to execute the packaged task despite it was not moved. This is UB and hence the runtime error !

You can improve this by checking if the packaged_task is [valid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/valid):

```
while (1)
{
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;  // to make sure that valid() checks this iteration
    {
       ...
    }
    if (t.valid())
        t();  // execute only if it's a valid task
    ...
}
```

**How to avoid endless looping ?**

You have somehow to keep track of what's running.  A simple technique is to used an `atomic` variable to manage a shared state information (which can be accessed concurrently without locking).

For example you could count the nimber of finished producers

```
std::atomic<int>finished{0};  // count the producers that are finished
...
```

void test_thread9_producerN()
   {
        cout <<"start producer"<

Then you can adapt your consumer to take inte account this information:

```
void test_thread9_consumer1()
{
    bool nothing_to_do{false}; 
    while (!nothing_to_do && finished<2)
    {
    ...   
        nothing_to_do=task_q.empty();  // in the lock protected section 
        if (!nothing_to_do)     
    ...
    }
}
```

**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/Zgfx0k)**

Answer (score 0):

```
void test_thread9_consumer1()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;
    while (1)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
            if (!task_q.empty())
            {
                t = std::move(task_q.front());
                task_q.pop_front();
            }
        }
        t();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

Lets trim this code down:

```
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;
    while (1)
    {
            if (!task_q.empty())
                t = std::move(task_q.front());
        t();
    }
```

Now we can clearly see the error: you try to call t() regardless of whether or not we fetched it.

```
void test_thread9_consumer1()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;
    while (1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
            if (task_q.empty())
                continue;
            t = std::move(task_q.front());
            task_q.pop_front();
        }

        t();
    }
}
```

You may want to continue your exploration of threads by looking at "[condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)"

For the second part of your question, you could consider changing the main thread to `join` all of the providers and then set a global flag indicating the work is done.

std::atomic g_producing;

```
void test_thread9()
{
    std::thread t1(test_thread9_producer1);
    std::thread t2(test_thread9_producer2);
    g_producing = true;

    std::thread t3(test_thread9_consumer1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    g_producing = false;

    t3.join();
} 

std::deque<std::packaged_task<int()>>task_q;
std::mutex lock9;

int factial_calc2(int in)
{
    int ret = 1;
    for (int i = in; i > 1; i--)
    {
        ret = ret*i;
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
    std::cout << "input is " << in << "result is " << ret << std::endl;
    return ret;
}

void test_thread9_producer1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
        std::packaged_task<int()> t1(std::bind(factial_calc2, i));
        task_q.push_back(std::move(t1));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void test_thread9_producer2()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 2)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
        std::packaged_task<int()> t1(std::bind(factial_calc2, i));
        task_q.push_back(std::move(t1));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void test_thread9_consumer1()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()>t;
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock9);
            if (task_q.empty()) {
                if (!g_producing)
                    break;
                continue;
            }
            t = std::move(task_q.front());
            task_q.pop_front();
        }
        t();
    }
}
```